# Difference between char[] and char* in function call

Tags: c++, c, char

I have found myself unable to explain why the following piece of code works. Needless to say, I am quite new to C++...

```
#include <cstdio>

void foo(char* p)
{
    p[0] = 'y';
}

int main()
{
    char a[1];
    a[0] = 'x';
    printf("a[0] = %c\n", a[0]);
    foo(a);
    printf("a[0] = %c\n", a[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

This program outputs

```
a[0] = x
a[0] = y
```

What intrigues me us that I am not passing a pointer, but an array, to foo. So how can foo change the value of the array a? Does this apply only to arrays of char?

The answer to [Difference between char and char[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120658/difference-between-char-and-char1), confirms my observation, but it does not go into detail about *why* this is the case.

Thanks!

Comment: Because when you're passing pointer you're passing the address of the object so you can change it's value; This is the case with your fragment e.g. you are not passing the value but the address to the object in this case char[];

Comment: Grab a good C beginner book and read. You can't learn languages from the Internet through tutorials. Or if you can, it takes quite a while longer than learning it through books.

Comment: @Aamir +1 You are write. Using tutorials you can solve problems sometime but you cant learn new technologies....

Comment: Remember when passing arrays in like this you also need to pass in the size of the array otherwise all sorts of "fun" can happen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C, arrays, in most contexts (*), decay into a pointer to their first element.

In your case, the array `a` decays into a pointer to `a[0]`.

The array `int arr[12][23]`, when used just by its identifier, decays to a pointer to its first element, namely `arr[0]`, which is of type `int (*)[23]` (pointer to array of 23 ints).

(*) Arrays do not decay when used as the argument to the `sizeof` operator, or when used as argument to the `&` operator or when used as initializer (a string literal) for a character array.

Comment: For completeness I'd mention that the "decay" is formally speaking *lvalue-to-rvalue conversion*, or "*the process of getting a value out of a variable*". C has this weird decision that "there are no values of array type, only objects", and when you try to take a value of an array, you end up with a pointer. And C is strictly call-by-value, so you can't pass an array itself to the function, only a pointer to the first element (like `int*`), or a pointer to the whole array (like `int(*)[10]`).

Comment: Hence an array itself cannot be a function parameter. A question arises why an array-like syntax can be used to specify the parameter type- and this eludes me completely. :-)

Answer (score 5):

When you're passing an array to a function it decays to a pointer to the first element.

The following are completely equivalent:

```
void foo(char* p);
void foo(char p[]);
void foo(char p[42]); /* Or any other number. */
```

> Does this apply only to arrays of char?

It applies to any array. I recommend the [aryptr section of the C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

When You say

```
char a[5];
```

the compiler allocates 5 sequential blocks of memory, and the **address** of the first block is assigned to a. So by definition name of the array (a in our case) is just a pointer to a memory location.

Now when we say a[0], compiler manipulates it as *(a+0*sizeof(array datatype i.e. char, int etc.)), symbolically a[i] is represented as *(a+i*sizeof(array datatype i.e. char, int etc.))

As far as function parameter passing is concerned When we pass an array to a function basically it is just the address of the first element which is passed. For more details regarding this plz follow [this link](http://www-ee.eng.hawaii.edu/~tep/EE160/Book/chap7/section2.1.2.html) or read the @cnicutar's answer (as he has already posted a correct answer there is no point repeating that again)...

Answer (score 1):

You can try this to convince yourself how this works.

```
int a[8], *p;
p = a;
printf("%p, %p, %p\n", a, &a[0], p);
```

Answer (score 0):

An array is nothing more than a pointer (to the first element), at least for argument passing sake.

Comment: I wouldn't say that (people will start downvoting this).

Comment: I already added a comment (only for argument passing), which was probably too late.

Comment: Thanks, I upvoted your answer (it's the best and most elaborated).

Comment: Actually pmgs is the best, I was just there sooner.

Comment: Yes I always upvote every good answer on my questions, not only the fastest, and then I accept the best or most elaborated.

Answer (score 0):

The three prototypes here are equivalent:

```
void foo(char *p);
void foo(char p[]);
void foo(char p[42]);
```

C says a declaration of parameter of type array of `T` is *adjusted* to a declaration of type pointer to `T`.

Answer (score 0):

Array name points to the address of the first element of the array. Please refer: [Is an array name a pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-array-name-a-pointer-in-c)