# Trailing Array Idiom

Tags: c++, c, arrays, terminology, idioms

What is **Trailing Array Idiom** ?

P.S : Googling this term gives *The vectors are implemented using the trailing array idiom, thus they are not resizeable without changing the address of the vector object itself.*

Comment: As others have commented on some answers below, you'd have better luck searching for _flexible array member_.

Comment: Note that, by strict definition, this invokes _UB_: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711233/is-the-struct-hack-technically-undefined-behavior

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you mean the trailing array idiom mentioned in the [GCC source code](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/gcc/gcc-5659/gcc/vec.h) (where your quote comes from), it seems to refer to the old C trick to implement a dynamic array:

```
typedef struct {
    /* header */
    size_t nelems;

    /* actual array */
    int a[1];
} IntVector;
```

where an array would be created with

```
IntVector *make_intvector(size_t n)
{
    IntVector *v = malloc(sizeof(IntVector) + sizeof(int) * (n-1));
    if (v != NULL)
        v->nelems = n;
    return v;
}
```

Comment: If it is referring to that, the more common term is the [struct hack](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3711233/168225).

Comment: @Georg: I dont think(although I am not sure) it is referring to that otherwise the term (as you've mentioned) `struct hack` would have been used in place of `Trailing array idiom`.

Comment: @Prasoon: The author might have just used a different term, would not be the first time someone did that. "Struct hack" sounds a bit informal anyway.

Comment: @Prasoon, this comment gives it away: "This means you cannot have variables or fields of vector type -- always use a pointer to a vector.  The one exception is the final field of a structure, which could be a vector type." I admit I've never heard it being called "trailing array idiom" either, but it makes some sense.

Comment: @larsmans : Yes it does make sense. Accepted your answer. `:)`

Comment: @Georg Fritzsche: Ironically, the term "struct hack" appears in the standard.

Comment: @aib only in the index to point to the standard terminology: 'struct hack, *see* flexible array member'

Comment: Am I the only one to find this "flexibility" extremely disconcerting. This gently violates any use of `sizeof`...

Comment: @Matthieu M.: like it or not, this is quite a common idiom in C (with at least three different names). I've seen it in operating system code, in libraries and now in GCC.

Answer (score 2):

I think what is meant is:

```
struct foo {
  ... some data members, maybe the length of bar ...
  char bar[]; /* last member of foo, char is just an example */
};
```

It is used by allocating with `malloc(sizeof(struct foo)+LEN)`, where LEN is the desired length of `bar`. This way only **one** malloc is needed. The `[]` can only be used with the last struct member.

And, as fas as I understand the GCC doc, `struct foo` can also only be (reasonably) used as last member of another struct, because the storage size is not fixed -- or as pointer.

Comment: This is called a "flexible array member" and is in the C99 standard (§6.7.2.1P16).

Answer (score 1):

It seems to refer to arrays in structs, which may have a variable array-size. See:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/08/26/220873.aspx
and
http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdbint/Support-Libraries.html

Another tip, if you google for an expression put the expression in "" like "trailing array" this will give you more specific results. Google knows about trailing arrays.