# Array declaration at the end of a struct?

Tags: c++

I just came across some code which declares a struct within a C++ class as follows:

```
struct T 
{
       int data;
       T* next;
} array[0];
```

What does this kind of declaration do? What effect does putting "array[0]" at the end of the struct defintion have?

Comment: Is it the last thing in the definition of the class?

Comment: @ruslik: No. It's in the private: section before some other inline functions.

Comment: Is there a `typedef` for `T`? Is the `next` field declaration valid without one?

Comment: `private` isn't valid in C. Did you mean to tag this question C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ahh, it's almost a *"flexible array member"*.

It was formalized in C99, but it's an old C trick that creates a dynamic array. Allocate more memory for the object and you can store more elements in the array.

I think the use of a specific `0` there is a compromise, as actual `[]` flexible arrays were not in C89 or C++.  The more canonical legacy use of this pattern is `...[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

This means, the struct definition is available only within that class.

Comment: Thanks. More specifically I wanted to know what effect does putting "array[0]" at the end have?

Answer (score 1):

It's an attempt to declare a type, `T` and an array of size zero of `T`. However, it is not legal to declare a zero sized array in C++. The code is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

In some compilers like [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) a [zero length array](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Zero-Length.html) is a synonym for a flexible class/struct member declared using the `[]` notation.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the case, but:

When a structure have to contain a variable length C string (that won't change after initialization), then instead of writing:

```
struct x {
    int key;
    const char* s;
};
```

when we'll need two `malloc`'s (one for struct, and one for string), we can write

```
struct X2 {
    int key;
    char s[1];
}x2;
// and use it like 
x2* tmp = (x2*)malloc(sizeof(x2) + strlen(str));
```

Here we have only one `malloc` for both, structure and the string.

When the last atribute of a structure is an array, then by allocating variable space for the structure we can allocate it with variable number of such members. I think this happens in your case.

Answer (score 0):

It is well known as c struct hack, but [take care](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711233/is-the-struct-hack-technically-undefined-behavior) when you use it