# the flexible struct in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I saw some code as following:

```
struct Hello
{
   int age;
   int time;
   int data[1];
};

struct Element
{
   int a;
   int b;
};

struct Element element_[5] = (/* Initiate the array */);
struct Hello* hello = (struct Hello*)malloc(sizeof(Element)*5);
struct Element * element_p = NULL;

element_p = (struct Element *)hello->data;

for(int i = 0; i<5; i++)
{
   memcpy(element_p, &element_[i], sizeof(struct Element));
}
```

for this line: `element_p = (struct Element *)hello->data;`, why we need to cast `hello->data to (struct Element *)`? And does this mean the operation on the pointer of `element_p` will does the same to the `hello->data`? and does this line will fill the address of each element of `struct Element element_[5]` to each element of `hello->data`?

Comment: First of all, that code won’t compile (`:` should be `;` and `；` should be `;` unless your compiler accepts `；`, which it doesn’t), and second, it looks more like C than C++ (and if it really is C++, it’s terrible).

Comment: I don’t judge anything. I’m just saying the code does not compile, and that is a fact, not an opinion. And it was unclear whether it was C or C++.

Comment: I modified the title and keywords of this post

Comment: @ratzip ok. Next time please take into account that C and C++ are **totally different languages**.

Comment: That is called a [struct hack](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?StructHack), there is an SO discussion about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711233/is-the-struct-hack-technically-undefined-behavior). You are not allocating anything in your example, but you can find examples how that is done in the first link.

Answer (score 8):

<del>This is horrible **horrible** C++.</del> The cast is needed because `hello->data` is actually an `int[]`, so not directly convertible to an `Element*`.

Moreover, it's undefined behavior, since `hello` isn't initialized and yet you dereference it (via `->data`).

Comment: why need this line?element_p = (struct Element *)hello->data;? does this mean we can use element_p to operate hello->data?

Comment: @ratzip you don't need that line, because that line is illegal. `hello->data` is illegal since `hello` wasn't initialized. If it was, then `p` would point to the memory location that `hello->data` points to. Modifying `*p` would modify `*hello->data`.

Comment: ok, how about hello is initiated maybe because I missed that

Comment: I am not the one write these code, I saw it and trying to understand it

Comment: @ratzip I explained what happens when it's initialized.

Answer (score 0):

`element_p` must be a pointer to `struct Element` but `hello->data` is `int data[1]`, so you need the cast. Suppose you initialized `hello` you "force" `element_p` to be a pointer to an area of memory where a single integer is, since in fact `hello->data` will point to the first and only integer "contained" in the array `hello->data[]`. Since `struct Element` "contains" 2 integer, `element_p->a` should access to `hello->data[0]`, but `element_p->b` would try to accesso to `hello->data[1]` which is out of the bound of the array.

The for loop will copy data of the size of the struct Element (very likely `2*sizeof(int)`), taken from each initialazed struct `element_`, into the are pointed by `element_p` that, as we've said and because of a missing part (see hack below), have room for just 1 int. Since `element_p` stays the same, you will overwrite that memory and only the last "struct" copied will survive.

As you showed to us, it looks like a good recipe for a crash. Anyway if the `hack`  Joe talks in comment about is in place, `element_p` will point to the first int of several other "ints". Since ints are nothing but memory, they could be enough to accomodate `struct Element` structs you could access with `element_p[0]` the first, `element_p[1]` the second and so on. Likely something like

```
  hello = malloc(sizeof (*hello) + sizeof (struct Element) * 6);
```

or alike. Now, `element_p = (struct Element *)hello->data` can be used.

Anyway the for loop continues to write over the same area, `element_p` needs to be advanced by 1 (1 whole struct `Element`) in order to fill each time a different area (`element_p+i` shoudl go).

Comment: `data` should be declared as `char[1]` and the size argument to malloc should subtract 1.

Comment: ok, thanks,  "since in fact hello->data will point to the first and only integer "contained" in the array hello->data[]." I do not understand it, what you mean?

Comment: @Joe why data should be char[1]? what is the reason/

Comment: `char` is the only type that is guaranteed to be 1, so you could simply subtract 1 when allocating storage. You could also just subtract `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: some extra bytes allocated, no harm...