# GCC: Tell the compiler that access outside array limits is allowed?

Tags: gcc, optimization

We have the following problem:

There are often structures that look like this:

```
struct {
    someType foo;
    /* The actual length of bar[] depends on the
     * size passed to malloc() */
    someType bar[1];
} example;
```

One example for such a structure is the "BITMAPINFO" structure in the Windows API, however, we are using similar structures on an embedded device (Cortex-M).

We are using the GNU G++ and the GNU GCC C compilers for ARM Cortex-M.

When we turn the compiler optimization on, the compiler makes the assumption that the array index lies inside the "valid" range when writing to the array. Here a very simplified example from some memory management code (the original code is more than 1000 lines long):

```
#include <cstdint>

typedef struct {
    union {
        uint8_t * pointers[ 1 ];
        uint8_t buffer[ 1000 ];
    } memory;
    uint8_t first;
    uint8_t last;
} StorageType;

void moveElements( StorageType & dataStorage ) {
    for(uint8_t i = dataStorage.first; i < dataStorage.last; i++) {
        dataStorage.memory.pointers[i] = dataStorage.memory.pointers[i - 1];
    }
}
```

The compiled code of the simplified example looks like this when using "-O1" with "g++.exe" of GCC 11.3.1:

```
    ldrb    r3, [r0, #1000] @ zero_extendqisi2
    ldrb    r2, [r0, #1001] @ zero_extendqisi2
    cmp     r2, r3
    bls     .L1
    add     r2, r0, r3, lsl #2
    ldr     r2, [r2, #-4]
    str     r2, [r0, r3, lsl #2]
.L1:
    bx      lr
```

Assuming that the array "dataStorage.memory.pointers[]" is only one element long (which is not the case), the compiler optimizes away the loop.

Question:

Is it possible to tell the compiler not to make (if possible) *any* assumptions or at least the assumption that arrays can be accessed outside their "official" boundaries?

Unfortunately, our project is very large (several million lines of code) and most of the code is third-party code that we don't want to touch or even generated code which is overwritten when building the project.

Comment: In this specific example, the array size should be `[]` ("flexible array member"). Then there should be no optimization shenanigans.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks for the comment. However, our main problem is that we have a large project (~ 27 million lines of code including third-party code) so modifying all corresponding code lines is not an option.

Comment: Looked through [the manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-13.2.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) Perhaps `-fno-tree-vrp -fno-vpa-vrp` will work? Maybe also `-fno-strict-aliasing`.

Comment: It shouldn't be hard to find all `[1]` declarations in structures and fix them. I'd be surprised if the third-party code contains this. Flexible array members are not a commonly used feature to begin with.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat this struct was [defined long before flexible array member was introduced](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58618191/995714) and it got stuck in the Windows API so you can't change it easily

Comment: *contains more expressions that are "undefined behavior" according to the C++ specs (but actually "machine-specific behavior").*  Umm, no.  It's undefined behavior.  Implementations are not precluded from supporting it as an extension, but in the absence of explicit support, it's not safe to use.

Comment: Don't look now, but I hear supercat coming down the hall ....  :-)

Comment: That's related to a priority issue.

Comment: To be clear: FAMs are the language spec's version of the "struct hack" demonstrated in the question.  FAMs should be a drop-in replacement, meaning only the definitions of the structures now using the struct hack should need to change, not any of the code using these structures.

Comment: I observe, however, that although you tagged the question C, in the body you talk about C++ and g++, too. If you need something that is compatible with both C and C++ then FAMs don't cut it, because C++ does not support them.  In that event, this is one of those rare questions that should be tagged both [c] and [c++].  That would also settle the question of whether updating the code is a viable possibility.

Comment: @JohnBollinger FAMs can't be a drop-in replacement for struct hack `...[1]` arrays.  The calculation for the size of a dynamically-allocated `struct` will change from `struct s *a = malloc(sizeof(*a) + (n - 1) * sizeof( a->array[0]));` to `struct s *a = malloc(sizeof(*a) + n * sizeof( a->array[0]));`.  Those allocations aren't going to be easy to find and update.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Re “ FAMs should be a drop-in replacement”: No, they should not. Code to allocate space for the structures defined with `[1]` may incorporate that into their calculation of size required, and changing it to `[]` may result is less space than necessary being allocated, thus causing use of the last element to destroy other data in memory.

Comment: @MartinRosenau 100% it will not optimize the if because of that. Your examples make no sense at all. Show ***real*** code, not this nonsense

Comment: @AndrewHenle They *might* be a drop-in replacement depending on how the size of the dynamically allocated struct was calculated. If it was something like `sizeof(*a) + n * sizeof(a->array[0])` or `offsetof(typeof(*a), array) + n * sizeof(a->array[0])` or `offsetof(typeof(*a), array[n])` then it would be OK.

Comment: @gulpr *100% it will not optimize the if because of that.* [Oh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16365149/gcc-optimization-bug-or-c-rule-broken)  Compilers *can* and *do* optimize code based on declared array sizes,  Exceed declared array bounds at your peril.

Comment: @IanAbbott True, but good luck trying to programmatically identify the possible variations correctly then modify them.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you very much. However, we have some problems: 1) We don't want to modify third-party code in the project. 2) In the first file where we saw that problem, the `[1]` does not appear in a `struct` but in a `union` - and in a union `[ ]` seems not to be allowed. 3) We fear that the compiler is making even more false assumptions.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I'm not even sure if it is undefined behaviour: `*(a+5)` and `(a+0)[5]` seem to be well-defined in such a case while `a[5]` *seems* to be undefined behaviour.

Comment: @MartinRosenau [C11 6.5.6p8](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.6p8): "... If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: @gulpr I updated my question. It turned out that the method called in my first example was only optimized away because it was inlined...

Comment: @AndrewHenle Thanks for the link. However, that text distinguishes between "the resulting pointer points to the memory after the *array*" (which is my case - and allowed according to that text) and "overflow" (which seems to have the meaning: "after the last address of the *RAM*" - which is not the case in my code).

Comment: @MartinRosenau I think the overflow it's referring to is similar to arithmetic overflow when you add two integers and the result exceeds the range of that integer type. As long as the original pointer and result are within the object (or 1 past the end), it's guaranteed that you won't get this kind of overflow.