# single malloc for creating 2 structs

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc

I have a node with this structure:

```
struct node
{
    unsigned long key;
    unsigned long value;
    struct node* lChild;    
    struct node* rChild;   
};
```

I have a dummy node which has default values:

```
struct node* newSpecialNode()
{
    struct node* node = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    node->key = 0;
    node->value = 0;
    node->lChild = NULL;
    node->rChild = NULL;
    return(node);
}
```

All nodes in my data structure will call this method to create a node.

```
struct node* newInternalNode(unsigned long key, unsigned long value)
{
    struct node* node = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    node->key = key;
    node->value = value;
    node->lChild = newSpecialNode();
    node->rChild = newSpecialNode();
    return(node);
}
```

I call the function `newSpecialNode()` for left and right child.
So there are two `malloc` calls. But whenever I create a node, I always create two dummy nodes.
So I wanted to do a single malloc which allocates memory for both `lChild` and `rChild`.
Possibly allocate a double word and reference its parts. But I do not know how to do it.

I tried this approach. But again I need to do two mallocs.

```
struct node** ptrToTwoNodes = (struct node**) malloc(2*sizeof(struct node*));
ptrToTwoNodes[0] = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
ptrToTwoNodes[1] = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

Comment: `struct node* ptrToTwoNodes = (struct node*) malloc(2*sizeof(struct node));`, `(ptrToTwoNodes)`, `(ptrToTwoNodes+1)`

Comment: One important thing to consider is that if you allocate multiple nodes in a single `malloc()` call, you'll need to free those nodes as a block.  This might mean that you will have to keep track of which pointer is the one to be freed and only free the block when *all* of the pointers to it are no longer in use.  If you need to be able to independently free `lChild` or `rChild` (or otherwise transfer ownership to other things that might hold pointers to a `node` probably), you should stick with separate `malloc()` calls.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21475414/allocating-several-arrays-of-the-same-type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to allocate a single block of memory for the two nodes, try

```
struct node* ptrToTwoNodes = (struct node*) malloc(2*sizeof(struct node));
```

then `&ptrToTwoNodes[0]` and `&ptrToTwoNodes[1]` will be pointers to your two nodes. BTW I guess you should remove C++ tag.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. The idea is simple and it did not strike me :)
Someone removed the `C++` tag for me

Answer (score 4):

While you technically can allocate all three nodes with a single `malloc()`, you really shouldn't because it breaks the recursive "symmetry" of the tree structure.

When calling `malloc()` three times, you get a tree where each node is independent of each other. That means you can *change* the tree later (adding and removing nodes) without having to worry how the child node was allocated.

The root of the problem is that you can't `free()` part of a memory segment returned my `malloc()`. You always have to call `free()` exactly once for each pointer returned by `malloc()` - no more and no less.

If malloc is too expensive for you, then an alternative is to create a set of helper functions that keep a pool of node structures (so they allocate N at once and then return one after the other until the pool runs out). See [object pool pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern).

Comment: Great explanation!!thanks.. 3 Reasons why I'm trying to do a single malloc. 1.I'm not doing any GC. 2. I'm using it in a concurrent setting and havn't figured out a GC algorithm. 3.These special nodes will never change values and they will will get replaced only by another internal node

Comment: Re 3: If "replace" means for you "change the l/rChild pointer", then keep in mind that this will create (small) memory leaks. My current feeling is that you have an idea how to solve a problem but that idea is bad. Maybe if you told us what problem you're trying to solve, we could offer you better alternatives.

Comment: Let us say, I create two mallocs (one for each child). When I "replace" a node (Yes I'm changing l/r child pointer), I still cannot release the memory of this replaced node. Reason being some other thread can still hold reference to it in a concurrent setting.
So till I figure out a GC for my algorithm, I planned to go with this approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can allocate memory for 2 nodes, and assign the pointer to a variable:

```
struct node* ptrToTwoNodes = (struct node*) malloc(2*sizeof(struct node));
ptrToTwoNodes[0].value = ...;
ptrToTwoNodes[1].value = ...;
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what is your end result, but you can do it like:

```
struct node
{
    unsigned long key;
    unsigned long value;
    struct node* Child;    //allocate two 2 node sized blocks for it & access left-Child[0], right-Child[1]
};
```

And Initialize as:

```
struct node* newSpecialNode()
{
    struct node* node = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    node->key = 0;
    node->value = 0;
    node->Child = NULL;
    return(node);
}
```

And then allocate like:

```
struct node* newInternalNode(unsigned long key, unsigned long value)
{
    struct node* node = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    node->key = key;
    node->value = value;
    node->Child = malloc(sizeof(sruct node)*2); //Child[0] & Child[1] 
    return(node);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify the code like follows:

```
struct node * newSpecialNode(void)
{
  struct node * node = malloc(2 * sizeof(*node));
  node->key = 0;
  node->value = 0;
  node->lChild = NULL;
  node->rChild = NULL;
  ++node;

  node->key = 0;
  node->value = 0;
  node->lChild = NULL;
  node->rChild = NULL;
  --node;

  return node;
}

struct node * newInternalNode(unsigned long key, unsigned long value)
{
  struct node * node = malloc(sizeof(*node));
  node->key = key;
  node->value = value;
  node->lChild = newSpecialNode();
  node->rChild = node->lChild + 1; 

  return node;
}
```

Take care on how to `free()` things.

Also add error checking to all those `malloc()`s.

Also^2: [In C there is no need to cast the result of `malloc()`, nor is it recommended.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: Do you mean I can safely replace `struct node * node = (struct node*) malloc(2 * sizeof(*node));` with `struct node * node = malloc(2 * sizeof(*node));` ?

Comment: @arunmoezhi: In C you should, yes.

Comment: will removing the typecasting improve performance? Practically I wont see any considerable change. But theoretically will it reduce the # of assembly instructions?

Comment: It will make your code safer, as the cast may easily hide bugs ... that's all.