# Passing char array to const void* param

Tags: c, pointers, casting

I have a structure like this:

```
typedef struct {
    float batch;
    float length;
    uint32_t test;
    char val[0];
}
PARAM;
```

And am calling a function with this format:

```
void fillValues(float val, float len, uint32_t tmp, const void* prw);
```

I declare the structure and allocate some memory:

```
PARAM *first = calloc(10, sizeof(PARAM));
```

The problem I am having is if I print the values of `first->data` before calling the function, it contains as expected but if I call the function:

`fillValues (test, first->batch, first->length,
             first->test, &first->val);`

and try and print prw inside, it contains nothing.

I think I am passing the value incorrectly because it is declared as a char array but the function parameter is a const void *.
P.S. I don't want to change the fucntion param type.

The only part where prw is used in fillValues is converting to a double:

```
double *value
value = (double*)first->data;
*value = *(const double*)pwr;
```

Comment: Sorry a few silly typos my mistake

Comment: @homeGrown that's why you should copy/paste your code here and not retype it.

Comment: @Michael Walz It's a huge function so did not want to add futile code

Comment: You can do this, it's perfectly legal. But please show the  `fillValues` function, there is most likely a problem with the `prw` parameter for a different reason.

Comment: `&first->val` -> `first->val`.

Comment: I meant copy/paste the relevant parts. What are yolu doing with the `prw` parameter in the `fillValues` function?  You cannot do anything of value with that parameter. You cannot read from it and you cannot write to it.

Comment: @Michael Walz added relevant code to question

Comment: Concerning your last edit: `prw` is not mentioned in this code snippet and `value = (double*)->val;` is not legal C. Don't retype your code, copy/paste it.

Answer (score 3):

`char val[0];` is nonsense, this is not valid C. Arrays cannot have size zero. The GCC compiler had a non-standard language extension that allowed this (as a 1990s fix to the old ["struct hack"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711233/is-the-struct-hack-technically-undefined-behavior)). This all turned obsolete in the year 1999 with the C99 standard, when *flexible array members* were added to the language.

Change your struct to this:

```
typedef struct {
    float batch;
    float length;
    uint32_t test;
    char val []; // flexible array member
}
PARAM;
```

Then allocate memory as

```
PARAM* p = malloc(sizeof(PARAM) + sizeof(n));
```

where `n` is the length you want the array `char val[]` to have.

---

Since your function has the format `const void* prw`, the last parameter in the call should be `first->val` and not `&first->val`.

This is a perfect example of why void pointers should be avoided when possible: they tend to hide bugs and block compiler warnings.